# How would you compute this scale scoring problem in R?

Tags: r

I have a scale with six items, Q1 to Q6. Response ranges from 1 to 5 for each item. I would like to compute a score conforming to this rule:

"If you scored a 4 or 5 ("often" or "very often") on at least 4 of those statements... "

I have a relatively hard time to program this. Do you have any tips?
G.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would help if you can provide a reprex: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Without any example data it is hard to tell which structure you have, but you could loop through the answers and check within every iteration if your condition (answer equals "often" or "very often") is true. If so, set a counter +1. At the end the counter indicates on how many of those questions the recipent answered with "often" or "very often".

Answer (score 0):

Hard to do without any coding example but this is an example of what you could do:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(ID = 1:5, Q1 = c(1,4,2,2,3), Q2 = c(4,4,3,5,3), Q3 = c(5,4,1,5,5), 
                Q4 = c(5,3,4,3,3), Q5 = c(5,5,2,5,4), Q6 = c(2,1,4,4,5))

dt[, Qx := ifelse(rowSums(dt[, -1] >= 4) >= 4, T, F)]
```

Which results to this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this ought to do it. TRUE / FALSE is great. You saved me hours of worktime. Virtual beer's on me.